# How can I make a circular disc component to move on a specific coloured strip and shouldn't move out of it?

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a feature for users to move a circular disc on a designated path strip on the page, I tried to use the react-draggable library. Still, the issue is that I cannot restrain the circle disc from moving out of the designated path strip on the page.
Can any one please help me?
[Thanks in advance!][1]

```js
<div
                style={{
                  width: "90%",
                  backgroundColor: "#DCDCDC",
                  height: "15px",
                  borderRadius: "20px",
                }}
              >
                <Draggable
                  bounds={{ top: -20, left: 0, right: 825, bottom: 170 }}
                  // bounds="parent"
                  axis={
                    position.x.toFixed(0) == 70
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 295
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 296
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 297
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 298
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 299
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 300
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 301
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 302
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 304
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 305
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 525
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 526
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 527
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 528
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 529
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 530
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 531
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 532
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 533
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 534
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 535
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 755
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 756
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 757
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 758
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 759
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 760
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 761
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 762
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 763
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 764
                      ? "both"
                      : "x" && position.x.toFixed(0) == 765
                      ? "both"
                      : "x"
                  }
                  onDrag={(e, data) => trackPos(data)}
                >
                  <div
                    style={{
                      // position: "absolute",
                      userSelect: "none",
                    }}
                  >
                    <ColorDisc />
                  </div>
                </Draggable>
                <div>
                  x: {position.x.toFixed(0)}, y: {position.y.toFixed(0)}
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Hi Ashish, welcome to StaackOverflow, please do add a snippet of the code you have till now, this will help the community understand your question better and provide you with better answer to your specific problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.